# Multivariable recurrence: Solving $c(n,k) = c(n-1,k) + c(n-1,k-1) = \binom{n}{k}$ by algebraic methods.

Tags: combinatorics, discrete-mathematics, recurrence-relations, binomial-coefficients

> Let $(c_{n,k})_{n,k=0}^{\infty}$ be defined by
>
> $c(0,0)=1$, $\:\:c(0,k)=0 \:\: \forall \: k > 0$
>
> $$c(n,k) = c(n-1,k) + c(n-1,k-1) \:\:\: \forall \: n \geq 1$$

I can show that the answer is

$$c(n,k)=\frac{n(n-1) \cdots (n-k+1)}{k!} = \binom{n}{k}$$

by recognizing that the binomial coefficients satisfy exactly

the same recurrence but is there another way at arriving at

this result by "algebraic methods"? I am just curios if there is.

Comment: Here's an approach using generating functions: https://justanothermathblog.wordpress.com/2015/06/19/generating-functions-and-binomial-coefficients/

Comment: @Math1000 Thanks!